# Importing large, varied Excels to Access with VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have a project to create an access database that will be able to import varied Excels (exports from a SurveyMonkey like program) with different number of columns, column names, and number of rows into access to then be cross-walked to set rows in a unified table (linked table on a SQL backend) for comparing data across surveys.

If I can get the excels into Access, I can do the rest, but I keep running into errors.

Below is the script I am trying to use. The script runs when a button is pressed. It grabs the file name from a text field staff would type into. I am trying to use DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet, but am getting "runtime error 3047 record is too large" (or other errors) for some of the files, though the largest cell length is 430 cells and there are only 75 columns.

Additionally, even if it works (which it does for some smaller excels), the column names get cut off, due to Access field name character limits (I attempted a work around by importing without column headers, but any column after 39 doesn't get included). Ideally the field names would be named F1, F2, etc. and then during import a table with fields (FieldName, ColumnName) would have the columns inserted so the table would look like

```
| FieldName | ColumnName
| F1        | [Column1 Name]
| F2        | [Column2 Name]
etc...
```

If there is a totally different way to handle this project, I'd be happy to go in a different direction. I'm really hoping there is a magician on here that can help me! TIA

Button script:

```
Dim NameOfTable As String
Dim NameOfFile As String
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset, db As DAO.Database, x As Integer
Dim FieldName As String

Dim NameOfTable2 As String

NameOfTable2 = "TableOfColumns"

NameOfTable = Me.cbxTable.Value
NameOfFile = "\\dcfs\teleforms\Data for Julian\Dashboard Data\BackUps\" & Me.cbxTable.Value & ".xlsx"

'-Does table  exist?  If true, delete it;
 If Not IsNull(DLookup("Name", "MSysObjects", "Name='" & NameOfTable & "'")) Then
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.Close acTable, NameOfTable, acSaveYes
        DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable = acDefault, NameOfTable
        Debug.Print "Table" & NameOfTable & "deleted..."
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    End If
'Create new tblTable

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
        TransferType:=acImport, _
        SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
        TableName:=NameOfTable, _
        FileName:=NameOfFile, _
        HasFieldNames:=True


'Testing column name grab

 If Not IsNull(DLookup("Name", "MSysObjects", "Name='" & NameOfTable2 & "'")) Then
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.Close acTable, NameOfTable2, acSaveYes
       DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable = acDefault, NameOfTable2
       Debug.Print "Table" & NameOfTable2 & "deleted..."
      DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    End If
    
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
        TransferType:=acImport, _
        SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
        TableName:=NameOfTable2, _
        FileName:=NameOfFile, _
        HasFieldNames:=False
```

Comment: Did you mean the 'largest cell length is 430 characters'? AFAIK, TransferSpreadsheet determines data type by analyzing first dozen or so rows of data. If that sets a field as short text type then import encounters cell with 430 characters, it won't fit. However, I thought it would just truncate the data. My reasearch indicates if import involves more than 4000 records, that can trigger the referenced error. Instead of importing, try just setting a link - `acLink`.

Comment: Hmm, I'll look into acLink. As for the truncation, I don't know. It just gives me the error message, so I'm assuming it doesn't do that. The excel only has 40 some rows, so that isn't the issue